# Is "bordureux" slang, or a misspelling, or...?

Tags: vocabulaire

I saw this comment somewhere:

> T'es drôlement bordureux toi :^)

--which, for context, was in response to this:

> Naufrage de la droite ? Macron se porte encore bien.

I can't find *bordureux* in any dictionaries, nor any references to it as slang, so I have to assume I'm missing a pun, or it's egregiously misspelled, or something like that.

Anyone know what it means?

Comment: Could be a new word. Peut-être: "tu es sur la bordure", mais après, je ne sais pas trop interpréter.

Comment: Maybe a funny "frenchization" of the word "borderline" with "bordure" = "border".

Comment: Oui c'est plus ou moins ce que je pensais.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is a jocular translation of "[edgy](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/uptodate/2010/09/100928_kyeutd_edgy_page.shtml)", so *audacieux, tendance, d'avant-garde, limite*.

I found this [dialog](https://www.reddit.com/r/france/comments/45wq9x/pourrionsnous_changer_l%C3%A9tiquette_news_en_quelque/):

> Topic: *Pourrions-nous changer l'étiquette "news" en quelque chose d'un peu plus français?*
>
> — *"Propagande" ?*
> — *deux-**edgy**-quatre-moi* (humorous phonetic translation for "**too edgy for me**")
> — *Deux **Bordureux** Quatre Moi*

Comment: Parce que Macron... n'est pas à droite. Hmmm.

Comment: Maintenant je peux dire ici aux US _two bordureux four moi_ ;-)

Comment: C'est quand même assez prétentieux, en fait. Mais bon.

Answer (score 2):

I think the meaning is more like "Borderline" in English. In France "Border" is translated by "Bordure". Simon Déchamps was saying the same at the top.

In your context :

> Naufrage de la droite ? Macron se porte encore bien.

Macron isn't really a "candidat de droite" in France, but not really a "candidat de gauche" either. He was under Hollande Presidency, so many people assume that he is more from "la Gauche".

So, when someone tries to say that the "droite" isn't shipwrecked because Macron is OK, it's like saying Macro is from "la droite", which is quite borderline...

> c'est bordureux quoi !